# VBA: Return 2nd smallest number from list

Tags: vba, excel

**Using:** Excel 2010, VBA

**Goal:** Return second smallest number (whether it's an integer or real number with decimals) from a list

**Example Dataset (I'd want it to return 10.123):**

> 11
>
> 9
>
> 26.0
>
> 37.123
>
> 45
>
> 10.123

**Problem:** I came across several threads that explain how to do this, but it seems like everything only pertains to integers. I need this to work for a list of values that are integers and real numbers (e.g., 1 and 1.2345).

**What I've Tried (but I think this only works for integers):**

```
For dblX = LBound(arrFwdTimes) To UBound(arrFwdTimes) - 1
    For dblY = dblX + 1 To UBound(arrFwdTimes)
        If arrFwdTimes(dblX) > arrFwdTimes(dblY) Then
            strT = arrFwdTimes(dblY)
            arrFwdTimes(dblY) = arrFwdTimes(dblX)
            arrFwdTimes(dblX) = strT
            End If
        Next dblY
    Next dblX
```

Comment: Could you not achieve this with the excel formula `=SMALL(yourRange, 2)`?

Comment: @Tom, thank you for your response. I could, but would prefer to do it completely in the VBA script, as it will be passed as a variable for additional use. My apologies - I did not mention that this is just a snippet of a larger code.

Comment: You can use worksheetfunctions in vba also, so `ans = WorksheetFunction.Small(YourRange,2)` Don't reinvent the wheel when you don't need to

Comment: @Tom, interesting...let me try that right now. That would be so much easier than what I've been trying with creating multiple arrays... : (

Comment: On a side note, what works for integers should work for doubles too. Your algorithm seems to be wrong though, but it is way too Friday for me to really think it through.

Comment: @Tom, amazing! So amazing and ridiculously simple. Can you post as an answer? : )

Comment: @vacip, haha! Well i'll take that as good feedback for a Friday. That's good to know, and I'm curious to research why mine failed then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve what you want. This is the same as using the `SMALL` formula function

```
ans = WorksheetFunction.Small(YourRange,2)
```

Comment: Again, thank you so much. This worked for me, and now I know about the worksheet functions in VBA also. Thank you.